# make login page with post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I want to make a login page. But the problem is that even though the data I entered is wrong, it redirects to the page. how can i fix this?

I only have email and password information in my table

```
const client = require('../../db')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //req.body

app.listen(2121, ()=>{
    console.log("Sever is now listening at port 5000");
})

client.connect();



app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await client.query(
      `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1 AND password=$2`,
      [email, password]
    );
    
    if (user.rows.length === 0) {
      res.send("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış");
    } else {
     res.send("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre doğru");// Eşleşen kullanıcı bilgileri varsa diğer sayfaya yönlendir
    }
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

this is my database code.when i run my database query in postman it works correctly

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../common/Navbar/Navbar';

const User = () => {
 
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:2120/login`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });
      

      if (response.ok) {
       
        window.location.replace(`/AdminPage.js`);
      } else {
        setError('Invalid email or password');
      }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(error);
        setError('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
    }
  };


  return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
    <div className="container text-center">
        <h1 className="my-5">Search for the Dormitory You Want</h1>
        <form className="d-flex" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter email ..."
            className="form-control"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter password ..."
            className="form-control"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          
          <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
        
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default User
```

this is my login page code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related backend side since when you are sending the wrong login and password, you are still responding as a `200` ok. By default the HTTP status code sent in a response from an Express application is 200 (OK). Instead of that, you can just throw an error message with `404` status. In addition, if there is another issue that is not related correction of credentials you may to response `500` status code as an internal error. I have added inside `catch`.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await client.query(
      `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1 AND password=$2`,
      [email, password]
    );
    
    if (user.rows.length === 0) {
      res.status(404).send("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış");
    } else {
     res.send("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre doğru");// Eşleşen kullanıcı bilgileri varsa diğer sayfaya yönlendir
    }
    
  } catch (err) {
     response
    .status(500)
    .json({ message: "Error in invocation of API: /login" })
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you! I did what you said and on thereact side it worked after updating the code.